# strange output from Stream plot when y range goes outside the function domain

Tags: plotting

This function `f = x*Log[y]` is defined for all `x` and for `y>0`

```
f = x*Log[y];
fdomain = FunctionDomain[f, {x, y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

so I expected `StreamPlot` to only show streams for `y>0` only, even if the range given in the command itself includes negative values. (may be one did not notice the y range includes something outside the domain).

But the stream plots are all missing from `y=0` to `y=1` and then start above that.

Why are stream lines missing from `y=0..1`?

```
f = x*Log[y];
p = StreamPlot[{1, f}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, -1, 3},
        Axes -> True, Frame -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
        ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

They show up, when changing the `y` range to start from zero:

```
f=x*Log[y];
p = StreamPlot[{1,f},{x,0,3},{y,0,3},
      Axes -> True,Frame -> False,AxesOrigin->{0,0}
      ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to Maple, for same function and same plot range, it shows correctly the streams for `0..1` for `y` even though the range asked for starts at `-1`

```
f:=x*ln(y);
plots:-fieldplot([1,f],x=0..3,y=-1..3,fieldstrength=fixed);
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Mathematica 11.3 on Linux

Comment: Same behavior in Mathematica 11.3 Win 10. Could make them show up with this. f = x*Log[y];
p = StreamPlot[{1, f}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, -1, 3}, Axes -> True, 
  Frame -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  StreamPoints -> 
   Evaluate[
    Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, 0, 3, .2}, {y, -0.2, 3, 0.2}], 1]]]

Comment: Use `{y,0,3}` and set `PlotRange` to whatever you want. That's for a workaround, if you need to know why, I'd ask WRI Support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are stream lines missing from y=0..1?

Fixed in 12.3

```
ClearAll[x, y];
f = x*Log[y];
p = StreamPlot[{1, f}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, -1, 3}, Axes -> True, 
  Frame -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]